# cURL hangs server when curl_exec is called.

Tags: php, apache, api, curl, localhost

Testing on a local environment (OSX Mavericks, apache server), a curl function is hanging the server every time is is executed.

The incriminating line of code is

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

which is initialised thus:

```
   //initialize and setup the curl handler
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    //execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

when executed (having had all the variables parsed) the page just hangs indefinitely. removing the curl_exec command "fixes" the hang problem.

> PHP 5.6.11
>
> curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0) libcurl/7.38.0
>
> OpenSSL/0.9.8
>
> Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)

this answer ([fixing curl_exec hangs in Windows 8 apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750515/fixing-curl-exec-hangs-in-windows-8-apache)) suggests that multiple sessions are the problem... I have tried terminating the session before curl_exec is called but it makes no difference.

I'm out of ideas to try! I have no debugging information because the server is hanging and not returning anything. If anyone has any ideas what I could try i'd be really grateful! Thanks.

Comment: Same here. I have spent a few days but still no luck, anyone could please help?

Comment: The problem was with the local environment setup. OSX can run php etc, but it's not set up well for it. Have you tried using MAMP? Are you testing on a local OSX environment? If so I'm sure MAMP will help. 

If that's not it, I tried quite a few things before I realised this, maybe there is another solution, but it's most likely your server setup.

Comment: Still no one answering on this issue. I'm also experiencing the same issue as of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with using OSX's built in server capabilities. Switching over to MAMP - a dedicated local web-serving application for mac - solved the problem.